# BST search function returns true on one machine and false on another

Tags: c++, g++, binary-search-tree

I have a BST program and this is my search function that returns true if the specified data (d) is found in a node.  When it is called, node *s points to the root node of the tree.

This program works perfectly when I compile it on my university's virtual machine, but returns false when I compile and run it on my macbook.  What would be causing a completely different output?  I added a line to print out the data of each node it passes through while searching, and it finds the node with the correct data, but still returns false.

I'd appreciate any help, I can't think of a reason why this function would break under a different compiler.

This is the information on my mac compiler

Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix

This is the information on my virtual machine compiler

g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Here is my BST search function:

```
  bool bst::search(int d, node *s){
  cout << s->data << endl;
  if(s->data == d){
    curRoot = s;
    return 1;
  }
  else if(d > s->data){
    if(s->right == NULL)
      return 0;
    else{
      if(s->right->data == d)
        pRoot = s;
      search(d,s->right);
    }
  }
  else{
    if(s->left == NULL)
      return 0;
    else{
      if(s->left->data == d)
        pRoot = s;
      search(d,s->left);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with the value returned from subsequent calls to `search`?

Comment: @dddd You're trying to apply binary search to a tree, binary search only works with sorted containers, how would you sort a tree?

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz my BST is sorted so that values less than the parent node are placed in the left node and values greater than the parent node are placed in the right node.  When I run an inorder tree traversal function on my tree, it returns the correct order, so I believe my tree is sorted.

Comment: @RyanJ I'm under the impression that this function only returns once, do subsequent calls return anything if they never reach the part of the function that returns 1 or 0?

Comment: @dddd I think you should do a search function that works on "unsorted trees" because well trees can't be sorted(assume you have a node of value 2 with children 4 and 5), leaving that aside, if there's a way your function doesn't return anything then that's undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz By definition, a Binary Search Tree (BST) _is_ sorted; such that the values of the left subtree of any given node are _less_ than (or equal to) the value of the parent, and the values in the right subtree _greater_. His algorithm choice holds.

Comment: @RyanJ ah, I see, I'll read on it :-)

Comment: @dddd think about it recursively (as you have recursive calls in your function now): Suppose you have a tree that contains "5" down at a leaf node, and you pass in the root node to your function. How might you think a search would work if you looked at your analysis of a node as "some data with two sub-trees", and you're defining a tree-search function? You can _recursively_ apply your search to the sub-trees of a given node until you find what you want (this is a depth first search). If you reach a leaf and don't find the data, then your node doesn't exist.

Comment: @dddd (cont.) Recursive function calls are treated like a stack. Each subsequent call pushes a function call onto the stack. When it reaches the base case (no more nodes, or your desired data), it needs to propagate the return value back up the call chain, so you can't just call the function and let it drop on the floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems/redundancies in your current function.
First of all, you need to return the value of your recursive function search() right to the top of the stack.

The redundancies are in the form of multiple NULL checks, multiple data equality checks. 
A condensed form of the function to serve the purpose is as follows-

```
bool bst::search(int d, node *s){
   if(s == NULL) {
      return 0;
   }

   if(s->data == d) {
      return 1;
   }

   if(d > s->data) {
      return search(d,s->right);
   }
   else {
      return search(d,s->left);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to think the search function should return only once... that's indeed how it should be for an iterative implementation.  So let's look at one, based on sray's simplification.

```
bool bst::search(int d, const node *s)
{
   while (s) {
      if(s->data == d) return 1;

      if(d > s->data) {
         s = s->right;
      }
      else {
         s = s->left;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This was possible because the recursion was tail-recursive -- we can just replace the arguments and loop.

Recursion itself doesn't work that way.  It works just like any other function call.  If you called `sqrt` inside your function, you wouldn't think that `sqrt` would replace your function, rather you would use the result in your calculation.  Same thing when you call your own function.  And sometimes recursive results need to be used for further calculation.  Consider this function to count the nodes in a tree:

```
bool count(const node *s)
{
   if (s)
      return count(s->left) + 1 + count(s->right);
   return 0;
}
```

It would do you no good to have the deepest calls set the return value for the whole tree.